# How to recover a docker container that is removed using kitematic

Tags: docker, containers, kitematic

I am using Windows.
I accidentally removed a container using the kitematic application. When I searched my machine I still can find traces of this under C:\Users\{mylogin}\.somedirectory\myContainer
The thing is how do I re-attach this and somehow recreate the container with the same content?

Comment: just an update, I will create a new container named 'copyOfMyContainer' whatever, and see if it creates a directory in the similar directory above, then I will try to copy the content of 'myContainer' into the new one and see if that works.

Comment: Yeah so that's it! I just needed to create a new container and copy the content from the old folder to the new folder. The trick is you need to find that old folder -- it should be pretty easy by searching on the machine. but it will depend on what your container does as well I guess.